# Grid of numbers and dashes, X-Akseli and Y-Ehe?

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle

I have been given this puzzle by my friend (who is a qualified military cryptographer). I am completely stuck as for what to do.

They gave me this hint:

"Don't take it so literal, think in all three dimensions."

What if it isn't a grid we are looking at - what if it's a cube?

Another hint:

"The puzzle was made on physical paper, I also solved it on physical paper Even when I made the solution to show Llama, I had to print out my digital spreadsheet for physical paper(edited) because only physical paper has three dimensions"

I have no idea where I'm going with this

[image]

Comment: @dcfyj not a whole lot, to be honest, cos im so stumped. i have found that akseli is finnish for aksis, but I have no idea what "Y-Ehe" is.

Comment: The only hint I have been given are "dont take the numbers too literally"

Comment: The same puzzle can be found here https://warosu.org/sci/thread/8842230 without anything about "qualified military cryptographers". I think that page may be a mirror of something 4chan-related.

Comment: "Akseli" appears to be Finnish for both "axis" and "axle".

Comment: oh, I take it back: there is something in the discussion there about the source of the puzzle being a military cryptographer. user36160, are you also the person who posted the puzzle there?

Comment: lol @GarethMcCaughan that was me posting on there as well! haha

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan you have any idea how to solve?

Comment: No good ideas as yet. Haven't thought about it much, though.

Comment: The text on it seems a bit awkward. I tried translating it back to Finnish with Google Translate and got "Annetut ankkurit. Loput ovat reikiä. Mitä jäljellä on polkuja. Löytää lineaarinen polku vähiten vastustuskykyä."

Comment: Or is it some sort of a tanglement puzzle?

Comment: I don't know what "Ehe" is, but it could refer to "eheys" which is Finnish for "integrity". And since we're talking about a cryptographer, maybe it means data integrity.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with least drawing resistance, like draw on it on a paper, and the ink will have resistance.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing to notice is that the the values of Y-ehe are multiples of the corresponding row.  45 is a multiple of 9, 40 a multiple of 8 and 14 a multiple of 7, etc.

The other thing is that the X-akseli and Y-ehe values sum up to the same value, 194.

If you look at the matrix, you see that the multiples in Y-ehe almost match the number of blank cells.  There are 2 empty cells in row 7 and Y-ehe(7) is 2x7.  So if you fill the blank cells with the row number, the cells in a row nicely sum up to the Y-ehe value.

Naturally you will want to compute the column sums, and you discover the X-akseli values.

[image]

Note however that you have to remove the initial 6 to make it work.  Probably a typo.

All this teaches us one thing: the value of a cell is the row number.

Now I will boldly assume, out of nowhere, that the goal is to go from the top-left to the bottom-right corner by minimizing the total cell count.  Here are 2 options:

[image]
and
[image]

The number at the bottom-right is the sum of all cells.  As you can see, the second path, with a score of 80, is better than the first one, with a score of 82.  It is longer but uses smaller cell values.  There are other paths, but they result still larger scores.  The solution on the right shows the optimal path.

I have no explanation about the mismatched sums or where the hint "Think in all 3 dimensions" comes into play.

Comment: I AM CLUELESS!!!!!!!! i really really apreciate the work, but i asked her and she said its incorrect. love you for doing this, though! (Spread this around, this is hurting me now! i need an answer)

Comment: ok, dude, so i sent her your answe, she said that the "6" was in fact a typo, but it was intentional, and it is one of only 2 typos!!!!!! you con do this, bro!

Comment: That first image is correct! you filled it in correctly!

Comment: It seems my guess about the final goal was incorrect after all.

Comment: Sorry to tell you this, but it starts to look like a "guess what I think" puzzle.  If you guess correctly what the riddler had in mind, you might get it, but else you are just shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried a few things, but haven't got that much, maybe someone can develop on this or find something I missed.

First off, using the numbers as $x$ and $y$ coordinates we can plot a scatter graph:

[image]

But as you can see there is very little correlation. Indeed using a spearman's rank calculator, we get a value of $-0.109244$:

[image]

So very little negative correlation.

All I can think off for the table, is that perhaps the values in each cell is $\sqrt{a+b}$ with $a$ being the corresponding horizontal value and $b$ the corresponding vertical value.

However this *really* doesn't give a nice table.

The last thing I tried was superimposing the graph on to the table:

[image]

Doesn't really give anything...

What I find really suspicious is that there are 9 x values and 9 y values.

However, despite these attempts I was unable to find anything. The only thing I can think of which I am sure about is the values for the diagonal cells ($-x$ means that the cell is a path and has an integer $x$.

Here is a copyable mathjax table:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
 & \text{1} & \text{2} & \text{3} & \text{4} & \text{5} & \text{6} & \text{7} & \text{8} & \text{9} \\ \hline
\text{1} & 1 & - &   & - & - & - & - \\ \hline
\text{2} &   & -2&   & - &   &   & - & - & - \\ \hline
\text{3} &   & - &-3 & - &   &   &   &   & - \\ \hline
\text{4} &   &   &   & 4 & - & - &   &   & - \\ \hline
\text{5} &   &   & - & - & 5 & - &   & - & - \\ \hline
\text{6} & - & - & - &   &   & 6 &   & - &   \\ \hline
\text{7} & - &   & - & - & - & - & -7& - &   \\ \hline
\text{8} & - &   &   & - &   &   &   & -8& - \\ \hline
\text{9} & - & - & - & - &   &   &   &   & 9 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: I really, really appreciate the work mate. I really hope someone else can build on it. you got further than I ever did

Comment: Please do check the edit, though. i feel if anyone can solve it, its you

Comment: @user36160 hmmm, 3d? In that case I imagine that the grid will give us a set of numbers we can use on the $z$ axis. I'll see if I can think of anything...

Comment: cheers, mate. i really think you can do this!